# how to use python regex find matched string?

Tags: python, regex

for string `"//div[@id~'objectnavigator-card-list']//li[@class~'outbound-alert-settings']"`, I want to find `"@..'...'"` like `"@id~'objectnavigator-card-list'"` or `"@class~'outbound-alert-settings'"`. But when I use regex `((@.+)\~(\'.*?\'))`, it find `"@id~'objectnavigator-card-list']//li[@class~'outbound-alert-settings'"`. So how to modify the regex to find the string successfully?

Comment: Please format question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non-capturing, non greedy, modifiers on the inner brackets and search for not the terminating character, e.g.:

```
 re.findall(r"((?:@[^\~]+)\~(?:\'[^\]]*?\'))", test)
```

On your test string returns:

```
 ["@id~'objectnavigator-card-list'", "@class~'outbound-alert-settings'"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit the characters you want to match between the quotes to not match the quote:

```
>>> re.findall(r'@[a-z]+~\'[-a-z]*\'', x)
```

I find it's much easier to look for only the characters I know are going to be in a matching section rather than omitting characters from more permissive matches.

Answer (score 1):

For your current test string's input you can try this pattern:

```
import re 

a = "//div[@id~'objectnavigator-card-list']//li[@class~'outbound-alert-settings']"
# find everything which begins by '@' and neglect ']'
regex = re.compile(r'(@[^\]]+)')
strings = re.findall(regex, a)
# Or simply:
# strings = re.findall('(@[^\\]]+)', a)

print(strings)
```

Output:

```
["@id~'objectnavigator-card-list'", "@class~'outbound-alert-settings'"]
```